# why move constructor is not called

Tags: c++

So I am new to move semantic and I am testing out the following code. My understanding is that rvalue will invoke the move constructor and I expected A("123") will cause the move constructor to be called. But when I ran this, the copy constructor is called instead.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

class  A
{
    std::string s;
    public:

    A(const std::string& in) : s(in) { std::cout << "ctor!\n";}
    A(const A& o) : s(o.s) { std::cout << "move failed!\n"; }
    A(A&& o) noexcept : s(std::move(o.s)) { }
};

class  B
{
    A d_a;
    public:
    B(const A& a) :d_a(a)
{}
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Trying to move A\n";
    B b(A("123")); // move-constructs from rvalue temporary

}
```

Comment: Please always include the header files needed to make your code compilable when asking questions here.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I disagree with this dupe and am reopening.  The OP's constructor is calling the constructor for `A` with an lvalue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is the constructor of `B`:

```
B(const A& a) :d_a(a) {}
```

The function parameter `const A&` is a const-qualified lvalue reference, which you can't cast to an rvalue. You need to change the constructor to (or add a second one)

```
B(A&& a) : d_a(std::move(a)) {}
```

As a side note, you get the correct move semantics for the types in your example for free, if you just define them as

```
struct  A {
    std::string s;
};

struct B {
     A d_a;
};
```

with the client code

```
B b{A{"123"}};
```

I understand that you wanted to not rely on compiler-generated special member functions for the sake of investigating the move-construction, I just didn't want to omit this shortcut, because this is the setup one should strive for: let the copy and move semantics of your class be automatically assembled by their data members.

Comment: aha, I see. So the entire chains also need to implement mctor

Comment: Isn't this the other way around? Basically you are casting an rvalue reference given as parameter to a const lvalue reference which then makes a call to copy constructor, doesn't it?

Comment: its the other way around, a rvalue ref would need to be converted to a `const` lvalue ref

Comment: "lvalue reference, which you can't cast to an rvalue [reference]" -- not true, there are circumstances when you can do it (not saying that this would be a good idea, though)

Answer (score 2):

A const lvalue reference binds to anything. Your `B` has a constructor that takes `A` by a const lvalue reference. When you pass a temporary `A` to this constructor, this will eventually lead to some parameter setting that looks like

```
const A& tmp = temporary_A;
```

and from then on, your A will be treated as a const lvalue reference which makes a call to copy constructor since that matches the signature. You need to define a constructor in `B` that takes `A` by an rvalue reference.

```
B(A&& a)
```

As things currently are, you will see a print out like:

> Trying to move A
>
> ctor!
>
> move failed!

`ctor!` is printed when constructing the temporary and since your parameter is taken as const lvalue reference `d_a(a)` calls the copy constructor. Below, modified code avoids copy.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

class  A
{
    std::string s;
    public:

    A(const std::string& in) : s(in) { std::cout << "ctor!\n";}
    A(const A& o) : s(o.s) { std::cout << "move failed!\n"; }
    A(A&& o) noexcept : s(std::move(o.s)) { }
};

class  B
{
    A d_a;
    public:
    B(A&& a) :d_a(std::move(a))
    {}
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Trying to move A\n";
    B b(A("123")); // move-constructs from rvalue temporary
}
```